# Are there successors to httprecon

Tags: webserver, fingerprinting, reconnaissance

httprecon appears to be dead, the latest update per [changelog](http://www.computec.ch/projekte/httprecon/?s=changelog) is from 2009. Are there any successors?

Comment: This is in the 'product recommendation' area: "what program can X?"